# CSS file not loading in Django

Tags: css, django

I have a CSS file being defined in my program and for some reason its not working...When I check'd with firebug the status is 200 OK but no changes occur..Not sure if there is any syntax issue with my CSS file.
Can you please provide your inputs

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from preview,view import *
import os

site_media = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'site_media')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
              (r'^catalog/$','home'),
              (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$,'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':site_media}),)
```

**css.css**

```
*{ 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
} 
html{ 
    font-size:medium; 
} 
html,body{ 
    background-color:Silver; 
} 
.cb{ 
    clear:both; 
} 
.fr{ 
    float:right; 
} 
.fl{ 
float:left; 
} 
.bn{ 
    border:none; 
}#main{ 
     margin: 0 auto; 
     width:900px; 
     background-color:White; 
} 
.bannerIEPadder, .sidebarIEPadder, .contentIEPadder{ 
     padding:10px;  
} 
.navIEPadder, .footerIEPadder{ 
     padding:5px; 
} 
#banner{ 
     width:900px; 
     height:75px; 
     background-color:DarkOrange; 
     color:White; 
     font-size:36px; 
     font-weight:bold; 
position:relative; 
} 
div.cart_box{ 
     position:absolute; 
     top:10px; 
     right:10px; 
     font-size:medium; 
} 
div.cart_box a{ 
     color:white; 
} 
#sidebar{ 
     width:200px; 
     float:left;; 
} 
#content{ 
     width:700px; 
     float:left; 
} 
#footer{ 
     clear:both; 
     background-color:#98AC5E; 
     color:White; 
     text-align:center; 
} 
a.skip_link{ 
     position:absolute; 
     left:-1000px; 
     top:-1000px; 
}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "XHTML1-s.dtd" ><html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head> 
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
     <title>{% block title %}{% if page_title %}{{ page_title }} - {% endif %}      
          {{ site_name }}{% endblock %}</title> 
     <meta name="keywords" content="{{ meta_keywords }}" /> 
     <meta name="description" content="{{ meta_description }}" /> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/css.css"
           type="/text/css"/>

</head> 
<body> 
     {% block site_wrapper %}{% endblock %} 
</body></html>
```

**catalog.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 

{% block site_wrapper %} 
<div id="main"> 
     <a href="#content" class="skip_link">Skip to main content</a> 
     <div id="banner"> 
          <div class="bannerIEPadder"> 
               <div class="cart_box"> 
                [link to cart here] 
                </div>
 Modern Musician 
          </div> 
     </div> 
     <div id="navigation"> 
          <div class="navIEPadder"> 
                [navigation here] 
          </div> 
     </div> 
     <div id="middle"> 
          <div id="sidebar"> 
               <div class="sidebarIEPadder"> 
                [search box here] 
               <br /> 
                [category listing here] 
               </div> 
          </div> 
          <div id="content"> 
               <a name=”content”></a> 
               <div class="contentIEPadder"> 
                    {% block content %}{% endblock %} 
               </div> 
          </div> 
    </div> 
         </div> 
         <div id="footer"> 
              <div class="footerIEPadder"> 
                   [footer here] 
               </div> 
         </div> 
    </div> 
    {% endblock %}
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "catalog.html" %} 

{% block content %} 
     <h2>Welcome!</h2> 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you actually view the CSS file when you visit `/site_media/css.css`?

Comment: I get the following msg once css.css is loaded msg is displayed...notification.min.css ABorted  s3.amazon.com...not sure why

Comment: since you can see view the css file and get a 200, it could be a caching issue. try reloading with ctrl + f5, or deleting the brower's cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of the link in your base.html from "/text/css" to "text/css".