# Django-serving CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, django

I am currently working on a django app and need to deploy the css style sheets which I am struggling to deploy e.g base_site.css. I am currently depolying an 'index' url which works fine, though need to link the css sheet- My setup is as follows:

3) Style sheet contents example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Tom/base.css" />
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what exactly is the issue that you are having? 404 error? what's your setup?

Comment: Hi Jeff-The URL is just refletcing the contents of my index.html page-I belive its because my referencing isnt working properly similar to the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298665/css-file-not-loading-in-django ......

Comment: e.g index.html links example.html links base.html links css ?

Answer (score 0):

In dev mode Django will happily serve your static assets for you. So for you example you would have something like this in your settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'path-to-your-app/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then your directory structure would look like:

```
static/
  Tom/
    base.css
```

And change the href of the  tag to:

```
/static/Tom/base.css
```

Django has really good docs about this topic, take some time to read through them:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thanks Larry-although this now works-the webpage is just showing the contents of the html page e.g body { 0px etc, none of the css page or formatting-am I missing something obvious?.

Comment: anyone help with why just the contents of the template is reflected in the URl? Thanks